# Temperature Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

The temperature at 1:00 PM was 74 degrees and at 6:30 PM it was 52 degrees. Assuming a constant rate of change, what was the temperature at 4:00 PM?

I believe that at 3:15 PM the temperature is 65 degrees, but I am not sure what's the temperature at 4:00 PM. Is it possible to represent the problem in an algebraic equation?

Comment: The usual problem amounts to solving

$$\frac{d}{dt} P = -kP$$

though assuming a constant rate of change implies

$$\frac{d}{dt} P = -k$$

Comment: The temperature dropped 22 deg in 330 min. So in 180 min (to 4pm) it drops 12 deg to 62 deg. In 135 min it drops 9 deg, so it was 65 deg at 3:15pm.

Comment: P means what? As far as I know this equation is a derivative.

Comment: @almagest Your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(t)$ be the temperature at time $t$.

Constant rate of change means $$\frac{\text{d}p}{\text{d}t} = a = \text{const.}$$

In other words, the function $p(t)$ must be a linear equation of the form
$$p(t) = at+b$$

Because $$p(t) =  \int p'(t)\;\text{d}t =\int a\;\text{d}t = at + C $$

To compute that line, we need two points on the line. The text gives us

$$p(\text{1:00 PM}) = 74°F$$
$$p(\text{6:30 PM}) = 52°F$$
You can now calculate the rate of change (that is, how much the temperature changed per time)

$$a = \frac{\Delta\text{temp}}{\Delta\text{time}} = \frac{52°F - 74°F}{5.5\text{h}} = -4 \;\frac{°F}{\text{hour}} $$
With that you can calculate the temperature at $t= \text{4:00 PM}$.

$$74°F + \left(-4 \; \frac{°F}{\text{hour}}\right)\cdot(\text{1 PM} - \text{4 PM}) = 74°F - 4 \cdot 3\;\frac{°F}{\text{hour}}\cdot\text{hour}= 74°F - 12°F = 62°F $$